# How to keep those animals out of my farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time that I want to start a farm for wheat, melons or sugar cane. Even with fence twice as high around it, animals seems to spawn on it and destroy my crops.

Since melon seed are kinda rare, it's annoying to lose all my melon crops because a chicken, sheep or cow step on it.

How can we make a farm so the animals won't step on your crops?

Comment: Lose nearby grass blocks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 1.8 mobs can spawn in certain biomes but they do not only spawn on grass. Now they spawn on the highest block (so as to prevent mobs from spawning in houses), so you should put a ceiling on top of your farm. Adding torches should provide enough light for your crops and prevent hostile mobs from spawning.

Comment: Oh, neat, so the mobs are spawning on *top* of the fence?

Comment: Err.. not only the fences, but in the water and on the blocks the torches are on.

Comment: That sounds about right. Would explain all those cows I found chilling in trees, anyway.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this answer? I've not seen this behavior in 1.8.

Comment: @lunboks So *that's* why I see so many sheep and cows doing a crazy vertical twitch trapped in my trees? Wow, I'd thought my server was just glitching or something.

Comment: @agf http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Spawn and http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/639466-922-update-animals-can-respawn-new-mobs-and-chicken-information-updated/ Animals can spawn on pretty much any block now. In my own experience they seem to be able to even spawn in water as I have seen large groups of animals just floating in the water quite a ways from shore.

Comment: This explains the Cliff Pigs.

Answer (score 7):

Put glass on top of the tilled area, so that only spiders, wolves, chicken, slimes and silverfish can possibly fit in the one meter high ground. To keep everything but chicken (and spiders?), simply lit the area and fence it. To keep the chicken and the pigs out, I simply carved out a room in my base and dedicated it to this purpose:

[image]

That leaves wolves, though. I'm afraid that you'll just need to right click them to make them stay put while you move here to harvest.

Now, so long as my base doesn't get run over by mobs, my crops are reasonably safe.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to help:

The pathway in your garden can not be grass (use stone, or gravel or something). That should stop most of the neutral NPCs from spawning, and aggressive NPCs won't spawn as long as your farm is well lit.

Second, you can make melon seeds out of the melon pieces, just put them in your crafting slot. (You can also rebuild a full melon from them if you wanted for even more carrying capacity)

A single height of fences should be enough to keep things out then.

Comment: Also worth noting: If your farm area borders on grass, the grass can spread to farmland blocks which have reverted to dirt after being walked on. Animals can spawn on those blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Break all the ground beneath your farm and replace in with dirt. Then outline the dirt with a 2 block thick stone layer. Finally, rebuild your fence.

Diagram (Top Down):

0 = Dirt and H = Stone

```
HHHHHH
HHHHHH
HHOOHH
HHOOHH
HHOOHH
HHHHHH
HHHHHH
```